# AngularJS filtering json data

Tags: angularjs

I have a column in mysql database called "month" and the values are 1 for January, 2 for February and so on.

In my AngularJS app, I use a get request to pull the json array from my php file. Is there a way to filter "data" so I can request only posts that contain the column month which would allow me to do an if statement, for instance if (month == 1){ filter only data which contain month value of 1}

Here is my code so far:

```
app.controller('TimeController', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
  $http.post('ajax/getQuotes.php').success(function(data){

      $scope.monthNumber = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'M');

    if ($scope.monthNumber == 1){


    }

     $scope.quote = data;


     angular.element(document.getElementById('log')).html(   $scope.monthNumber);


  });
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include('../includes/config.php');

try {

    //Connect to the database, store the connection as a PDO object into $db.
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$DB_NAME.";host=".$DB_HOST.";charset=utf8", $DB_USER, $DB_PASS );

    //PDO will throw PDOExceptions on errors, this means you don't need to explicitely check for errors.
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //PDO will not emulate prepared statements. This solves some edge cases, and relives work from the PDO object.
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    //Prepare the statement.
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM quotes");

    //Execute the query
    $statement->execute();

    //Fetch all of the results.
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //$result now contains the entire resultset from the query.

    //create a temp array
    $arr = array();

    //loop through mysql tables
    if ($statement->execute()) {
        while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $arr[] = $row;
        }
    }
    array_unshift($arr, null);
    echo json_encode($arr);



    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $db = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}




?>
```

Is it possible to do a for each loop and push json data?

```
$.each {      if $scope.quote.month  == 1){          items.push ;         }  }
```

Comment: Why dont you pass the month to the *mySql* db? and let the database filter?

Comment: Yes, the month column is located inside mysql db. Yes, I could filter the month but does this mean that I need 12 files like               $http.post('ajax/month1.php').success(function(data){$scope.month1 = data;});

Comment: No! You would pass the month you need as a parameter to php which then receives it as a variable and builds the query accordingly.

Comment: Also, don't modify html elements from a controller. Just use `<div>{{ monthNumber }}</div>` in your view to display the month number.

Comment: Thanks guys. Please anyone could give me an example? I have been spending hours and still scratching my brain